# innerHTML from Javascript String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have a JavaScript string with HTML content inside it.

e.g.

```
var HTMLtext = 'text <div id="test-div-1">this is <b>just</b> a div</div><div id="test-div-2">this is <b>just</b> another div</div> more filler text';
```

I am looking to get the **innerHTML** from the first *div* element within this string. When I try using:

```
var testDiv1 = HTMLtext.getElementByID("test-div-1");
```

I get the error

> HTMLtext.getElementByID is not a function at window.onload

Are there any workarounds without putting HTMLtext in a temporary container?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c36tp6Lx/)

Comment: Your `HTMLtext` variable is a string not html element. What you are trying to do is same as if you would try `'this is some text`.getElementById('id')`. If you want to get the div with id you would have to do som regex string search.. What exactly are you trying to acomplish?

Comment: Never use regex for parsing html.  Search on SO to see numerous discussions on the subject.  Just parse it using either jquery or another parsing library.

Comment: I'm using AJAX to get the responsetText for a query and I want to split up the data being returned. I understand it's a string but I figured there would be some way to convert it temporarily. I'm fine using jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have jQuery in the question tags this is very simple...

```
var testDiv1 = $("<div/>", { html: HTMLtext }).find("#test-div-1").html();
```

That creates a non-DOM element, sets the html value and then parses and gets the inner html of the div you want.

[Here's an updated version of your jsfiddle...](https://jsfiddle.net/fwueufef/1/)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. For some reason it won't work when I try it in JSFiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/fwueufef/

Comment: Okay, my bad.  You can't use `$()` unless you're creating an element.  I've modified it to create an empty div, add your HTMLtext and then parse for the div in question.

Comment: Thank you. There's a couple great answers here but yours seems to solve my problem the simplest way.

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)

Comment: If you dont get any specific div id you can use this `var testDiv1 = $("<div/>", { html: HTMLtext}).find("div").html();` BTW Good Solution @Archer

Answer (score 1):

```
var HTMLtext = 'text <div id="test-div-1">this is <b>just</b> a div</div><div id="test-div-2">this is <b>just</b> another div</div> more filler text';
var tempDom = $('<output>').append($.parseHTML(HTMLtext));
$("#test-div-1",tempDom);
```

Parse the string to create HTML and create a temporary DOM so that jquery can traverse it.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments, there is no string (prototype) function getElementByID. You are likely thinking of [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). To use that, you would have to create an element with [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), set the innerHTML to the html string, add the element to the DOM (perhaps hidden so it isn't visible) with [document.body.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), then use document.getElementById() (note that the D is lowercase). But that would be creating a temporary container.

jQuery does simplify this a bit. It still requires creating a container but it doesn't have to be appended to the DOM. After creating an element with [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2) and setting the html with [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html), use [jQuery.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find the element with the [id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).  Then use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get the html contents of the first element found.

```js
var HTMLtext = 'text <div id="test-div-1">this is <b>just</b> a div</div><div id="test-div-2">this is <b>just</b> another div</div> more filler text';
var testDiv1 = $('<div>').html(HTMLtext).find('#test-div-1');
console.log(testDiv1.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```